# Como colocar mas de 1 imagem no fundo de uma pagina Web css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho 4 imagens e não sei como colocar elas no mesmo plano de fundo, como faço isso alguem pode me ajudar.

plano de fundo

Answer (score -1):

Oie!!!

Vc pode tentar colocar várias imagens no plano de fundo de uma página usando CSS, combinando várias propriedades CSS.

Uma maneira de fazer isso é usar a propriedade `background-image` para cada imagem que você deseja adicionar ao plano de fundo e, em seguida, *"empilhar"* essas imagens usando `background-position` e `background-size`. Se quiser mandar seu código aqui, fica mais fácil de ajudar :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).